# Difference between thermally isolated and adiabatic expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics

In thermodynamics is an expansion in a thermally isolated system exactly the same as an adiabatic expansion or is there a difference, please can you explain either way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thermally isolated system**

> In thermodynamics, a thermally isolated system can exchange no mass or heat energy with its environment, but may exchange work energy with its environment. The internal energy of a thermally isolated system may therefore change due to the exchange of work energy.

**Adiabatic system**

> An adiabatic process is one that occurs without transfer of heat or matter between a system and its surroundings; energy is transferred only as work.

So you can see that the terminology or nomenclature may be different but the meaning is the same.